# nextjs Image custom image loader downloads much larger images than the one in 'sizes'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

Here's the index.js

```
import Image from "next/image";

function imageLoader({ src, width }) {
  const dir = src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf("/"));

  if (width <= 320) {
    return `${dir}/320.webp`;
  } else if (width <= 480) {
    return `${dir}/480.webp`;
  } else if (width <= 640) {
    return `${dir}/640.webp`;
  } else if (width <= 750) {
    return `${dir}/750.webp`;
  } else if (width <= 828) {
    return `${dir}/828.webp`;
  } else if (width <= 1080) {
    return `${dir}/1080.webp`;
  } else if (width <= 1300) {
    return `${dir}/1200.webp`;
  } else {
    return `${dir}/1920.webp`;
  }
}

export default function Start({ countries }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ width: "300px" }}>
        <Image
          src="/large-image.jpg"
          alt="Large Image"
          loader={imageLoader}
          layout="fill"
          objectFit="cover"
          sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, (max-width: 900px) 50vw, 300px"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In `/public`, I have image files `large-image.jpg` and `<width>.webp`
What I expect is that

- showing full width image when the screen width is smaller than 600px,
- showing half width image when the screen width is between 600px and 900px,
- and showing 300px width image when the screen width is larger than 900px

and when I try 300px-> 1500px, it always use 1200px image.
This is the element inspect on the browser:

```
<img alt="Large Image" src="/1920.webp" decoding="async" data-nimg="fill" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;border:none;margin:auto;display:block;width:0;height:0;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;min-height:100%;max-height:100%;object-fit:cover" sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, (max-width: 900px) 50vw, 300px" srcset="/480.webp 384w, /640.webp 640w, /750.webp 750w, /828.webp 828w, /1080.webp 1080w, /1200.webp 1200w, /1920.webp 1920w, /1920.webp 2048w, /1920.webp 3840w">
```

srcset and sizes looks ok, what's wrong in this code?
Thank you!